# Htaccess with URL parameters - order

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I've two patterns that need to be redirected.

```
www.example.com/tag/value to www.example.com/recipe-tag/value
www.example.com/?tag=value to www.example.com/recipe-tag/value
```

This is my current .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^tag/(.*) http://www.example.com/recipe-tag/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

This works for the first redirect. What should I do to get the second redirect working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a condition to detect query string. Give this a try.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tag=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/recipe-tag/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^tag/(.*) http://www.example.com/recipe-tag/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Let me know how that works for you.

Comment: Works. Thanks a lot !

Comment: There is an issue in this. I want the pattern to pick only when it is like www.example.com/?tag=value.

This picks it even when "tag" is present elsewhere in the URL. How to validate this pattern?

Comment: try changing `tag=(.+)$` to `^tag=(.+)$`